# Streamreader to display

Tags: c#, io, streamreader

I'm still on my first step on C# and this is my first post/question.
How do I implement Streamreader to Display(output)
Like after clicking the Dataretrieve button I want to retrieve the data located on "D:\Savedata.txt" and display it on the lblDisplay

This is my code, am I missing something?

```
void DataretrieveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StreamReader read = File.OpenText("D:\\Savedata.txt");
   lblDisplay.Text = "Last Name: " +textBox1.Text.Trim();
   read.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how objects work, what variables are? What does `StreamReader` do? What ends up in the `read` variable? Where are you using this `read` variable?

Comment: Why do you expect that the `TextBox` contains the text of your file? You've created a `StreamReader` but you  never use it.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be what you're looking for.

```
void DataretrieveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("D:\\Savedata.txt"))
    {
        lblDisplay.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

When you create an instance of a class that implements interface IDisposable, you should wrap it in a using() statement to make sure the resources for it are freed when you leave the using() scope. Also, you can look over the documentation for StreamReader [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) which should help you see what's available.

Answer (score 2):

There is very handy static method [`ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) in `File` class, which will open a text file, read all lines of the file, and then close the file:

```
lblDisplay.Text = File.ReadAllText("D:\\Savedata.txt");
```

Internally this method does exactly what you are trying to implement (creates `StreamReader` and reads all characters from the current position to the end of the stream):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8, true, 0x400, true))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `read.ReadToEnd()`.